# laravel error assigning collection to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

in the controller from repository using the same abstract methods all() included:

```
    $clients = $this->clients->all();
    $substrates = $this->substrates->all();
    return view('jobs.create', compact('substrates', 'clients')) ;
```

in the create.blade.php

```
    let substrates = {!! $substrates !!}
    let clients = {!! $clients !!}
```

I can access the collection in embedded php in the html and works fine, however when I assign it to a javascript variable; although $clients has no problem works fine, I get the following:

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must return a string value (View: /home/vagrant/code/resources/views/jobs/create.blade.php)

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess the question I should ask is why i can't seem to change neither the array nor the collection into json, using json_encode() and toJson() same result "false"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `toJson()` method:

```
let substrates = `{!! $substrates->toJson() !!}`
let clients = `{!! $clients->toJson() !!}`
```

Comment: thanks I tried it and I get 'create:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: substrates is not defined' I'm using vue.js but all this is outside the vue instance.

Comment: $substrates = $this->substrates->all()->toArray();
    $temp = json_encode($substrates);
    dd($temp, json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg(), $substrates);
This is the dd() output: false 8 "Type is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use both the toJson() method or the @json Blade directive:

```
let substrates = @json($substrates);
let clients = @json($clients);
```

You can find a little documentation under rendering Json 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` for this:

```
<script>    
  let substrates = {!! json_encode($substrates->toArray()) !!};
  let clients = {!! json_encode($clients->toArray()) !!};
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried all the options including yours, when I console.log(substrates) i get not defined. although clients works perfectly and I can parse both, $clients and $substrates in php/html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I had a Binary Field in substrates model and as part of the collection; was getting all().